# Access lost column name after extracting from a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I have a matrix:

```
a<-c(0,1,3,5,56,3)
b<-c(1,4,3,10,3,50)
c<-cbind(a,b)
c<-as.matrix(c)
```

Then I create a subset of c:

```
d<-c[1,1]
```

I would like to get the columname for d. colnames(d) does't work.

Comment: It's a rather bad idea to create an object named `c`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`[` will drop dimensions by default when possible, which here causes the structure to change from a matrix to a vector.  Disable this behavior:

```
x <- cbind(a,b)
d <- x[1,1,drop=FALSE]

> colnames(d)
[1] "a"
```

Note that you didn't lose the names.  They just were no longer column names:

```
d <- x[1,1]
names(d)
[1] "a"
```

In the case where you have row and column names, and use the default of `drop=TRUE` while choosing a single element, names will not be present in the result.  R can't know whether you want to retain row or column names.

```
rownames(x) <- letters[7:12]
names(x[1,1])
NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to disable this behavior by default? So that `[` never drops the dimension except if specifically asked to do it.

Answer (score 0):

try using "names" instead of "colnames"

```
names (d)

[1] "a"
```